# Figure not shown in python tkinter gui

Tags: python, matplotlib, tkinter, figure, dpi

I'm using tkinter to write a simple gui to read some data, do some calculation, and plot the output. I'm working on a mac, using python 3 in a Spyder IDE.

I plan to separate the gui window into two frames: left one with some input entries and buttons, right one for plotting. Below is a minimum working example with only one button for exit, and a simple plot.

```
import tkinter
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
import numpy as np

class App(tkinter.Tk):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.set_figure()


    def set_figure(self):

        fig = Figure(figsize=(8, 8), dpi=25)
        t = np.arange(0, 3, .01)
        fig.add_subplot(111).plot(t, 2 * np.sin(2 * np.pi * t))

        fr1 = tkinter.LabelFrame(self, width = 300, height = 100)
        fr1.pack(side='left', fill='both', expand = 1)

        fr2 = tkinter.LabelFrame(self, width = 300, height = 100)
        fr2.pack(side='left', fill='both', expand = 1)

        canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, master=fr2)
        canvas.draw()
        canvas.get_tk_widget().pack()

        button = tkinter.Button(master=fr1, text='Quit', command = self._quit, width=25)
        button.pack(side=tkinter.BOTTOM)        

    def _quit(self):
        self.destroy()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = App()
    app.mainloop()
```

The problem is that when the dpi of the figure is small, nothing will show on the right frame. For example, if figsize is set to (8,8), the figure will not show if dpi is smaller than 29. But it will work if dpi > 30.

I tried and tested a bit, and it seems that is a limiting value for figsize*dpi. Smaller than this value, the figure won't show up. And this value depends on a few things, especially the size of the button size.

I don't have any clue about this. I guess it might be related to my setting of the matplotlib and probably, my os and screen (13 inch Mac retina). Any help would be appreciated.

[image]

Comment: When I run the code I get [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U19of.png).

Comment: code works corectly on Linux Mint